# How to add Private Frameworks into Project?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, frameworks, xcode4

I have a framework that's part of my app and I want to add it as a private framework so I can distribute it.  However, I couldn't find a way how to do it.  Apple does provide steps on how you should add private frameworks, but they're too brief to follow.  If anyone can point my to the right way on how to do this, I'd be really glad.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple already provided steps for [Embedding a Private Framework in Your Application Bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-106880). You should read this document.

Comment: I did look at it.  But the problem is that I don't understand what I'm suppose to do.  I just want people to elaborate on what specifically am I suppose to do.

Comment: The documentation the answer links to is too abstract to be very useful. It explains the high-level picture, but it does not e.g. name build setting names, and permissible values with their formats. Also, it sounds like it had not been updated for XCode 4.

Comment: @febeling if you know better solution then add another answer.

Comment: @SIGSEGV I downvoted because this is one of those answers, which basically say RTFM, but the referenced fine manual is quite lacking. The documentation does state to answer how it works, but it doesn't really. So the answer does not help me, and I that's what I mark with a downvote. What is missing from the documentation I explained in the comment above. Also I was a bit angry. Sorry about that. If you write how to do it in XC4 I'm happy to reverse my voting.