# jailbroken iOS: how resume(in foreground) from background

Tags: iphone, ios, background, jailbreak, foreground

I have problem. I need solve this problem for **jailbreak iOS**. My application works in background mode. I want that application go to foreground mode from background after some events. 
I tried next instruction:

```
system([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uiopen \"%@\"", @"appname://"] UTF8String])
```

But application didn't run from background. App run as new process.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User private API:

```
   int SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFStringRef displayIdentifier, Boolean suspended);
```

It's defined in SpringboardServices private framework.

You will need to add entitlement "com.apple.springboard.launchapplications" for this to work.

Comment: I add entitlements:
<key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key><true/>
And add instruction:
BSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("app.id"), NO); But when I build my app, I have error:
"Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_BSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier", referenced from:
      _displayStatusChanged in GlobusAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". How add SpringboardServices framework in my project??? Thank you!!!

Comment: First of all. It it's "SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier" and not "BSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier". Look at these question regarding adding private frameworks to project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201525/how-to-import-private-frameworks-in-xcode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322010/how-to-add-private-framework-to-target-dependencies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754070/how-to-add-private-frameworks-into-project

Comment: So, I successfully add private framework, but I have new problem. How I must right add entitlement?
I did next:
1. Create file 123.xml with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>

Comment: 2. Did next instruction ./ldid -S123.xml AppName.app/AppName
But after this ldid didn't finish and require enter something(didn't write what I must enter only empty row. I must exit  by pressing ctrl+z)

Comment: @kvofreelance: I am not sure. I would recommend to ask this as a separate question.

Comment: So I successfully added entitlement.xml via ldid.
But I have other questions:
1. I didn't checked Targets->AppName->Summary->Entitlements (is it true or false ?)
2. I create AppName.ipa which consist with:
ItunesArtwork, Payload->(Globus.app, Info.plist)
I installed app via iTools. MyApp is run but can't do some function. I try authorization via Internet. But when I install app without added entitlement an do some instruction with ldid, application working fine.
Please help me

Comment: @kvofreelance: please write a separate question (it's good stackoverflow practice to write a question for each concern). And give more details in that question on what functionality doesn't work in your case and how it fails.

Comment: Roni: I create separate question on link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347180/how-add-entitlement-via-ldid